# Star Rating System trying to insert value into db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hi I am using [Nashio/star-rating-svg](https://github.com/nashio/star-rating-svg)

I have setup everything regarding the displaying of the stars and also the hover works really well but the problem is I cannot get it to take the value and insert it into my db, it says in the documentation something about a callback function but it is not working for me. Here is what I have so far:

Insert the stars into html:

```
<div class="my-rating"></div>
```

Code that initializes the stars and gets them running:

```
<script>

        $(".my-rating").starRating({
            starSize: 45,
            <?php
                if(Login::isLogged(Login::$login_front)) {
                    echo "readOnly: false,";
                } else {
                    echo "readOnly: true,";
                }           
            ?>
            disableAfterRate: false,
            callback: function(currentRating) {
                $rating = currentRating;
                <?php
                      $addRating = $objRating->addRating($client_id, $rating);
                ?>
            }
        });

    </script>
```

The problem is not the php code that is trying to add the rating to the db but the problem is that function is not being called or started to execute and insert at all, also the stars don't even show when I insert the callback part, any help with anyone that has managed to get this working would be a great help, I look forward to your replies.

Comment: You want to execute a **PHP** code each time **Javascript** `callback` is called. Please make an Ajax request! and you must learn about server/client side programming !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my entire answer. It's tested and it is working:

Main file where stars appear and users click to rate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rating</title>

        <!-- Add the plugin's CSS (make sure of path) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/star-rating-svg.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Display the stars on page -->
    <div class="my-rating"></div>

    <!-- Add jquery.min.js -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add plugin's required JS (make sure of paths) -->
    <script src="src/jquery.star-rating-svg.js"></script>

    <!-- Initiate the plugin -->
    <script>
        $(".my-rating").starRating({
            starSize: 25,
            callback: function(currentRating, $el){

                $.post('submit_rating.php', {rating: currentRating});

            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP file `(submit_rating.php)`, that inserts the rating into database, should be in the same directory or adjust the path in your `$_POST` request above if you plan to keep that file in any inner directory. Save that file as `submit_rating.php` and in that file, you will receive the rating value as `$_POST['rating']`; Then you can insert that value to your database something like this:

`$rating = $_POST['rating']; // don't forget to sanitize`

And then insert the `$rating` into database. I hope this helps.

Comment: I made a bit of a mistake if you look up I just edited the top part it is not <input.. but it is <div class="my-rating"></div>, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Also I tried doing exactly what you proposed but nothing happens, think you could clear this up for me, I am really in a nutshell here, thank you for helping out friend.

Comment: @Blu3 I have updated my answer, please check. It's tested and it is working. Double check your main file to ensure that you are dong things correctly.

Comment: still no luck, nothing is happening when I click the stars its like the value is not being passed to the submit_rating page, if you have any ideas much help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Blu3 It works, nothing will happen on front-end, but the submit_rating.php file should insert the rating into the database. I have tested it. Double check your query to ensure that it actually works.